# Python pandas dataframe with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to index the following pandas dataframe with the following sample values. The dataframe has a lot of duplicates.

```
ID      AccountName
83      CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
83      CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
83      CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
83      CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
104     UNIVERSITY
104     UNIVERSITY
1740    ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
1740    ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
1740    ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
1740    ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
...
```

The resulting dataframe should be the following.

```
  ID        index   AccountName
  83            1   CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
  83            1   CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
  83            1   CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
  83            1   CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY
 104            2   UNIVERSITY
 104            2   UNIVERSITY
1740            3   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
1740            3   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
1740            3   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
1740            3   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO
...
```

Does anyone have an fast and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Does the order of the groups matter? Or just that duplicates all have the same group?

Comment: If you don't care about the order, you could use `df.groupby('AccountName').ngroup() + 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want an increasing index for each new ID, I'd do:

```
In [43]: df["number"] = df.ID.rank(method='dense').astype(int)

In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
     ID           AccountName  number
0    83  CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY       1
1    83  CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY       1
2    83  CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY       1
3    83  CHRISTIAN UNIVERSITY       1
4   104            UNIVERSITY       2
5   104            UNIVERSITY       2
6  1740   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO       3
7  1740   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO       3
8  1740   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO       3
9  1740   ELECTRIC CORPORATIO       3
```

which will give the lowest ID the number 1, and the second lowest 2, etc., independent of the order they actually appear in the frame (e.g. if you put ELECTRIC_CORPORATIO second, it'll still get #3 because 1740 is the third number.)

There are other ways if you can be guaranteed that your clusters are contiguous, e.g.

```
(~df["ID"].duplicated()).cumsum()
```

but that's much less reliable in general than mapping a unique ID to a unique number, IMHO.

Also, I've used "number" here as the column name rather than "index", because that causes confusion between the frame's index and your column named "index".